# Concise xpath query doesn't work using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The first xpath query works, but the second does not:

First set:

```
FieldElementParent_obj = Driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(text(), '%s')]/following-sibling::div" % FieldTitle)
FieldElement_obj = FieldElementParent_obj.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=".//div[contains(text(), '"+FieldData+"')]")
```

Second set:

```
FieldElementTitle_obj = Driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(text(), '%s')]" % FieldTitle)
FieldElement_obj = FieldElementTitle_obj.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="./following-sibling/descendant::div[contains(text(), '"+FieldData+"')]")
```

Why not?

Answer (score 0):

In the second line of the second block the *xpath* is missing the reference node, which you can mention as *`self`* as follows:

```
FieldElementTitle_obj = Driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[contains(text(), '%s')]" % FieldTitle)
FieldElement_obj = FieldElementTitle_obj.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=".//self::following-sibling/descendant::div[contains(text(), '"+FieldData+"')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short version:**

Your locators are different in the two sets (see the long version for a detailed comparison), that's why they might not act the same. At lot of it will depend on the structure of the DOM you are using them against.

**Long version:**

In your two "sets", you are splitting a locator into two parts and searching for them separately. If you combine each into a single locator and then compare, you can see the difference. NOTE: I turned

```
//div[contains(text(), '%s')] % FieldTitle
```

into

```
//div[contains(text(), '"+FieldTitle+"')]
```

for ease of comparing but they both work the same.

First set:

```
//div[contains(text(), '"+FieldTitle+"')]/following-sibling::div//div[contains(text(), '"+FieldData+"')]
```

Second set:

```
//div[contains(text(), '"+FieldTitle+"')]/following-sibling/descendant::div[contains(text(), '"+FieldData+"')]
```

In the Second set, you don't specify what element type (e.g. DIV) the `following-sibling` should be so you'll get whatever is the first sibling... it might be a DIV, it might not but it will depend on the structure of the DOM.

The next difference is `//div` vs `/descendant::div`. These will act the same unless the current node is a DIV... so, again it depends on your DOM. From the spec:

> // is short for /descendant-or-self::node()

See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev) for more info.